# How to compare datetime in cakephp4

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, cakephp, compare

I am using the following code to compare DB DateTime and the input field DateTime is equal or not but it not working, please help me out from this problem-

```
$appointment_time = $this->Appointments->find()->select(['appointment_time']);
$appointment_time1 = $this->request->getData('appointment_time');
$dt = ($appointment_time == $appointment_time1);
```

Comment: Assuming the appointment times are exactly equal, `$dt` will return `true`. Otherwise it will return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Always try to use the `debug()`function for your variables to understand the difference.

```
debug($appointment_time1);
debug($appointments);
```

In your case, `$appointment_time` is not what you expect, but `\Cake\ORM\Query` object. While `$appointment_time1` is a string.

**Try:**

```
// convert posted string to date time format
$appointment_time1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->getRequest()->getData('datetime')));

// fetch data from db
$appointments = $this->Appointments->find()->select(['appointment_time']);

foreach ($appointments as $appointment) {
   echo $appointment->appointment_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') == $appointment_time1 ? 'OK' : 'NOT OK';
}
```

**or**

```
$appointment = $this->Appointments->find()->select(['appointment_time'])->first();

echo $appointment->appointment_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') == $appointment_time1 ? 'OK' : 'NOT OK';
```

also try:

```
$appointment->appointment_time->getTimestamp() == strtotime($this->getRequest()->getData('datetime'));
```